# Question about the Cortex-M3 vector table placement

Tags: cortex-m

I am trying to understand the placement of the vector table for Cortex-M3 processor.

According to the Cortex-M3 arch ref manual, the **reset behavior** is like this (some parts are omitted):

[image]

So, we can see that the `vectortable` comes from the `VTOR` (Vector Table Offset Register).

According to the Cortex-M3 tech ref manual, the `VTOR` is defined as:

[image]

So we can see, it has a **reset value** of `0x0`. **So based on the above 2 criteria, the Cortex-M3 processor expects a vector table at the absolute address 0x0 in the Code area after reset**.

But in my MDK uVision IDE, I see my application is placed in the `IROM1` area, which starts at `0x8000000`, which is within the 0.5G `Code` memory area according to the Cortex-M3 memory map.

[image]

And since it has the `Starup` button checked, I guess that means the `IROM1` area should contain the vector table (**please correct me if I am wrong about this**).

So I think the vector table should lie at the beginning of `IROM1` area, i.e. `0x8000000`. And it is indeed so. Below pic shows that at the beginning of `IROM1`, it is the vector table's 1st entry, the SP value.

[image]

And what's more strange, the `VTOR` register (at `0xE000ED08`) still holds a `0x0` value:

[image]

So, how could my vector table be found with a `0x0` VTOR reset value?

And just out of curiosity, I checked the memory content at `0x0`, there contains exactly the same vector table content as `IROM1`. **So who did this magic copy??**

[image]

### ADD 1 - 4:39 PM 10/9/2020

I guess there must be something I don't know about the `startup` check box in below pic.

[image]

### ADD 2 - 5:09 PM 10/9/2020

Thanks to **@RealtimeRik** and **@domen**. I downloaded the datasheet for STM32F103x8_xB(https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf). In section 4 Memory mapping, I saw below diagram:

[image]

So it seems the [0x0, 0x8000000) range does get aliased to somewhere else. But I haven't found how to determine where it is aliased to...

### ADD 3 - 5:39 PM 10/9/2020

Now I found it!

I downloaded the [STM32Fxxx fef manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (btw it's really huge).

In section *3.4 Boot configuration*, it specifies the boot mode configured through the `BOOT[1:0]` pins.

[image]

And with different boot mode, different address aliasing is used:

> Depending on the selected boot mode, main Flash memory, system memory
> or SRAM is accessible as follows:
>
> - Boot from main Flash memory: the main Flash memory is aliased in the boot memory space (0x0000 0000), but still accessible from its
>   original memory space (0x800 0000). In other words, the Flash memory
>   contents can be accessed starting from address 0x0000 0000 or 0x800 0000.
> - Boot from system memory: the system memory is aliased in the boot memory space (0x0000 0000), but still accessible from its original
>   memory space (0x1FFF B000 in connectivity line devices, 0x1FFF F000 in
>   other devices).
> - Boot from the embedded SRAM: SRAM is accessible only at address 0x2000 0000.

What I saw is *Boot from main Flash memory*.

Well finally I can explain why `0x800 0000` is chosen...

### ADD 4 - 3:19 PM 10/15/2020

The placement/expectation of the interrupt vector table at the address 0 is similar to the IA32 processor in real mode...

Comment: this is all documented you should always have the proper documentation handy before starting this work. as you eventually found address zero is mapped to one of a few places depending on strap pins or nonvolatile bits that determine the mapping at zero, ideally you want to use the real flash address in the vector table not zero based...each chip vendor is different if they map at all and if so where, even within the stm32 family there is more than one ideal address to place the vector table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "Magic Copy". 0x00000000 is aliased to 0x08000000.

The actual memory is physically located at 0x08000000 but can also be access at 0x00000000.

If you look in the processor specific reference manual you should find this in the the memory map section.

Comment: Thanks but I checked the Memory Map section of the Cortex-M3 tech ref manual. It mentions the `bit-banding` feature but that's only for the first 1M address space of **SRAM** and **Peripheral** memory regions. It seems irrelevant to what I saw in **Code** region.

Comment: You should look into your chip's manual as well. For example for STM32 chips, you'll find this: "• Boot from main Flash memory: the main Flash memory is aliased in the boot memory space (0x0000 0000), but still accessible from its original memory space (0x800 0000). "

Comment: Thanks, I just checked the `STM32F103x8_xB` datasheet(https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf). I see something about the aliased memory for range `[0x0 ~ 0x8000000)`. I will update my question. Thanks! It looks promising.

Comment: As @domen states, you need the specific chips manual. For example it is in the STM32xxxx reference manuals.

Comment: arm has nothing to do with chip implementation arm simply reads the vector table at 0x00000000 first few items.  Then does the first fetch based on that, it is all chip vendor after that (atmel, st, nxp, etc) arm has nothing to do with it, arm docs are not involved.

Comment: @old_timer Thanks for pointing out the separation of duties between ARM and chip vendors. That really clears things up for newcomers.

Comment: In STM32 chips, you can read or set what you want to alias to addres 0x00000000 with SYSCFG_MEMRMP register. Obviously you can only change it during runtime.